# Why won't this Regex work in R

Tags: regex, r

I have tried grep, grepl, regexpr, gregexpr and all return failures or non-integers.

Ojbect is "test" and it is a character string with addresses. Example provided:

```
[9972] "1350 Hwy 160 W\nFort Mill, SC 29715"                                                                 
[9973] "Sonoran Desert Dentistry\n9220 E Raintree Dr\nSte 102\nScottsdale, AZ 85260"                         
[9974] "3252 Vilas Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527"                                                              
[9975] "224 W Cottage Grove Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527"                                                     
[9976] "320 W Cottage Grove Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527"                                                     
[9977] "7914 State Road 19\nDane, WI 53529"                                                                  
[9978] "106 Dane St\nDane, WI 53529"
```

The goal is to extract everything after the last "\n" so just the City through zipcode remain. like "Cottage Grove, WI 53527"

Here is a sample of the grep and regex that does not work:

```
> grep("\\[^\\]+$", test)
integer(0)
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: There's no backslash in those text lines. You need to learn that `print` output of character values with escaped characters is different than `cat` output. Read `?Quotes` and try `cat` on some of the lines. ( ... and I think that `"[^\\]"` is going to match anything.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`grep()` does not alter text. It only finds it and gives back the match index or the match itself.  To alter the matched text, you want to use `sub()` or `gsub()`. In this case, `sub()` is appropriate since you want to remove everything up to the last line-break once in each string.  The following should do it.

```
sub(".*\n", "", test)
# [1] "Fort Mill, SC 29715"     "Scottsdale, AZ 85260"    
# [3] "Cottage Grove, WI 53527" "Cottage Grove, WI 53527" 
# [5] "Cottage Grove, WI 53527" "Dane, WI 53529"
# [7] "Dane, WI 53529"
```

- `.*` is greedy, matching anything
- `\n` is what we're looking for

Since `.*` is greedy, this will remove everything up to and including the last `\n`.

**Data:**

```
test <- c("1350 Hwy 160 W\nFort Mill, SC 29715", "Sonoran Desert Dentistry\n9220 E Raintree Dr\nSte 102\nScottsdale, AZ 85260", 
"3252 Vilas Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527", "224 W Cottage Grove Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527", 
"320 W Cottage Grove Rd\nCottage Grove, WI 53527", "7914 State Road 19\nDane, WI 53529", 
"106 Dane St\nDane, WI 53529")
```